# Visual Studio 2010 Search Change Sets In Multiple Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, changeset

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 using TFS, how would do you determine all the files that were updated on a particular day?  All my research shows that you can search the change sets for a particular file, but not change sets for multiple files.

Comment: First of all, what is your source control software?

Comment: @RubenBartelink: I know it's probably TFS. But I don't want to make efforts to guess thinks. I believe the OP must make a minimal effort to describe precisely it's setup. And when something is not clear, I'll ask the OP to precise the point.

Comment: @RubenBartelink: you are probably right. I'll try to be a bit more pedagogic the next time;)

Comment: This is my first post to stack overflow so I apologize for any unclear setup details.  I appreciate your patience! :)

Comment: @SteveB We are using TFS, sorry for not specifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use the free [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) application for this kind of thing.

Using the *Code Review* sidekick you can search for changesets on a given date:

[image]

Once the changesets have loaded, select them all and click OK and you get a list of all changed files along with the changeset id, username and comment:

[image]

I have no affiliation with the software but I think it's excellent and use it all the time!

Comment: This would definitely solve my problem!  Thanks a lot, I will look into this.  It looks like it will save me a lot of time during my daily audit of work done by my group.